# Rails login partial in different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

Hey,
I'm pretty new to rails and for learning effect, I try to implement my own authorization system.
Right now I'm having a Page Controller to control some static pages and nothing more, and a Session Controller where I plan to implement most of the authorization process.

My problem is, I have no clue how to get my partial to use the sessions-controller, when I add it to one of the static pages controlled by the pages controller.

It stated out with this http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#top but i don't want it on an extra page.

so I tried setting the routes and I got an exception "no path found for '/'" as soon as I deleted "resources :sessions" it worked fine again.

my partial looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(User.new) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Login" %>
<% end %>
```

there's also a div class="action" block around the submit but can't find out how to escape it

this is included into my home via

```
<%= render 'sessions/new' %>
```

Thanks for your help

edit my solution:
I added to routes.rb:

```
resources :sessions
```

Furthermore I changed form_for(@user) to

```
<%= form_for(:session, url => sessions_path)
```

so this works.

Answer (score 0):

I Highly recommed that you look at the railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch , it will give you an idea how to create authentication without forgetting some important steps.

Then you can use the `gem devise` which is an excellent authentication gem.

Comment: thx but it doesn't really help. the authentication was only the first point where I found this problem. let's say e.g. I try to add a search for everybody as a partial on the same page. I'll still gonna have a page controller and let's say user controller, cause I also want to search while logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your functions and everything for authentication within a Session Helpers file?  Then, in your Application Controller if you add "include SessionsHelper" this should give you access to all the helper functions from Session that you should need

Comment: As a side note if your main problem is with the partial then I would take a look at this SO article [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031905/rails-calling-action-from-view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031905/rails-calling-action-from-view) I had a similar problem not too long ago and this helped me out

Comment: Thanks this suggestion actually gave me an idea that works :)